# What is the dimensionally smallest 2-seat helicopter?

Tags: helicopter

Considering only a two place helicopters (2 crew, or 1 crew and 1 passenger).

Comment: Which dimension are you looking for? Length over all, rotor diameter, cabin width, fuselage length, height or weight?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Sum of LOA, rotor diameter and height. Imagine some cubes. Of all 2-seat heli's which could be contained inside smallest cube?

Comment: See: [List of ultralight helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ultralight_helicopters)

Answer (score 1):

My vote would be for the [RotorWay Scorpion II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RotorWay_Scorpion#Scorpion).  Tiny little things would fit in a living room!

[image]